# How to mange file system of android mobile using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

For reading the mobile file system, I have used following Cordova code. Its working fine

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
    function (fileSystem) {
        var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
        reader.readEntries(
          function (entries) {
             ..
```

Additionally, I want to provide following functionalities using Cordova

•   Creating new folder

•   Delete file/ files

•   Rename

•   Get details

•   Remove files/ folders

•   Cut, copy and paste – single file and folder / multiple files and folders

•   Search function(in  depth search like windows explorer)

Could you please provide any suggestion to implement these functionalities/ code blocks?

Comment: There is a plugin found on cordova for file read/write etc, the angular version of that would be better to use.

Comment: @bala Cordova file plugin is suffice to handle all the operations you mentioned. You gotta be more precise while seeking help as to where exactly you want the code to fit in.

Comment: @Gandhi ionic framework is angular centric, it helps to use the angular version of cordova, *hint* ngCordova which fits in better with the framework.

Comment: @t0mm13b Thanks for the info. Was trying to explain Bala to be more specific about the sample code he is looking for

Comment: @Gandhi i have used angular with ionic  "angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {" inside the code block i have tried to perform reading file system using cardova

Answer (score 1):

There are two entry in cordova file API

- FileEntry
- DirectoryEntry

To perform operation on file e.g-Delete file,Get details of file you have to go to the file FileEntry. Similarly, to perform operation on folder e.g-Delete folder you have to go to the DirectoryEntry. And after going to that entry there are specific methods that you can perform.I just giving example of creating a folder as follows:

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("FolderName", {create: true});
```

For other operation i refer you to this Documentation:
[Phonegap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL`,So you are familiar with file plugin of cordova.
These are the things you can achieve using file plugin:-
To create a folder :-

```
var root = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(root,  
function(directoryEntry) {  
directoryEntry.getDirectory('your_dir_name',{create:true},successCallBack,errorCallBack);  
},function(e){});
```

To Remove file:-

```
var root = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory/file.txt;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(root,  
function(file) {  
file.remove(successCallBack,errorCallBack);  
},function(e){});
```

To Copy/move :-

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('YOUR_FILE_PATH/1.txt', function(fs) {
 var pathToCopy = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"/";
 var newName = "NEW_FILE_NAME"; //After copy/Move
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToCopy,function(directoryEntry) {
               fs.copyTo(directoryEntry, newName, function() {
                 console.log("File Copied To:"+pathToCopy);
               }, failFiles);
           });
}, failFiles);
```

To rename to file you can use both paths same and change the file name.

Hope this helps